# Problema con ejb y jsf jpa

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, ejb

Tenemos una tabla donde hay un saldo y un numero de cuenta pero al buscarla

```
int ct = cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta).getsaldo();
cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta).setsaldo(ct + depositar);
```

no me setea el saldo, en el sql no me lo setea, si alguien me puede iluminar en que falla mi logica (nroCuenta y depositar son int que entran) muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente deberías separar el get y set de los atributos, más que todo por cuestión de orden. Te quedaría algo así:

```
Cuenta ct = cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta);
int saldo = ct.getsaldo();
ct.setsaldo(ct + depositar);
cuentaFacade.edit(ct); // Este es necesario para que se refleje en la BD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int ct = cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta).getsaldo(); (optienes el saldo)
cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta).setsaldo(ct + depositar);  (buscas la cuenta y SI le seteas el saldo)
```

Sin embargo ten en cuenta que:
`cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta).setsaldo(ct + depositar);` te retorna un objeto (que no guardas en ningún lado,por lo tanto cuando la traza del programa pasa por esta linea busca el objeto, le setea el saldo y avanza a la siguiente linea por lo que el objeto con el nuevo saldo se pierde.)

Deberías hacer algo como:

```
Cuenta ct = cuentaFacade.find(nroCuenta);
int saldo = ct.getsaldo();
ct.setsaldo(ct + depositar);
cuentaFacade.edit(ct); // Este es necesario para que se refleje en la BD
```

Tal como te recomienda @Garrizano